# Using the global angular-cli in order to build my app

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-cli

I have a build process (TFS) for gated check-ins.
The build does the follow:

- Get latest soruce
- `npm install`
- `npm run build`
- `npm run build:test`
- more stuff...

The `npm install` part takes 2.9 minutes mostly because it installs angular-cli.
I have the angular-cli installed globally on the machine, why can't I use the global installation?

If I try to remove @angular/cli from my devDependencies, I got the error:

`You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command after reinstall of angular-cli`

Versions:

- @angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.0
- node 6.2.0
- npm 3.8.9
- Windows 2012

Comment: if I had to make a *guess*, I would think you probably have an older beta of angular-cli installed globally (`beta.28` or earlier).  The angular CLI project has changed from `angular-cli` to `@angular/cli`, and projects created with `@angular/cli` aren't compatible with the older releases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can remove the local install of @angular/cli, but I agree, this would be nice. To speed up you installs, switch from using npm to a faster package manager yarn. After installing yarn, your commands will look slightly different:

```
yarn install
yarn run build
yarn run build:test
```

But you'll definitely see the speed improvement. I blogged about Yarn here https://yakovfain.com/2016/11/06/angular-cli-speed-up-installing-dependencies-with-yarn